# Profiling firefox plugin

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

When I use firefox it slows down every 10 seconds and my mouse turns into an hourglass. I have tried closing and restarting firefox. One of the plugins is causing this problem. Any profiler that will figure out which plugin is consuming Firefox resources?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the [perf-html.io](https://perf-html.io/) profiler plugin ([github page](https://github.com/devtools-html/Gecko-Profiler-Addon)) which can take mixed profiles (javascript and native) and also [highlights latency spikes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Performance/Profiling_with_the_Built-in_Profiler#1._Timeline) in its timeline.